# How to put these two accordion inline in bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am walking through the example the bootstrap:

```
<div class="accordion" id="accordion2">
  <div class="accordion-group">
    <div class="accordion-heading">
      <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseOne">
        Collapsible Group Item #1
      </a>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="accordion-body collapse in">
      <div class="accordion-inner">
        Anim pariatur cliche...
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion-group">
    <div class="accordion-heading">
      <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseTwo">
        Collapsible Group Item #2
      </a>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="accordion-body collapse">
      <div class="accordion-inner">
        Anim pariatur cliche...
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now the output looks like this:

```
Collpasible Item 1#
Collpasible Item 1#
```

But I want output looks like:

```
    Collpasible Item 1#  Collpasible Item 2#
    occupy with the reusult of item 1 if 1 is clicked

 Collpasible Item 1#  Collpasible Item 2#
    occupy with the reusult of item 2 if 2 is clicked
```

Adding simple `inline` didn't work.

Comment: You can use another css file to overwrite the css... Use width:30%; float:left; It will come in one line.

Comment: use `float:left` and `clear:both` for eachone

Comment: create a class and call it or .accordion-group .accordion-heading{width:30%; float:left}

Comment: Yes but the results come on right. I want result to come below but two accordin on the same side. I am sorry, I am not good at CSS.

Comment: can you please explain a little more, I am unable to understand

Comment: I think you need to use jquery for that...onclick just change the width of the .accordion-heading

Comment: @user2032220 You may be wanting to use the accordion incorrectly - I think what you want is tabs. Take a look at [Bootstrap's tabs](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#tabs).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to be using Tabs (or pills), not Accordion. Don't forget to add the JS file needed. More: http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#tabs and http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/components.html#navs

From the Docs:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab">
  <li class="active"><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#profile">Profile</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane active" id="home">...</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="profile">...</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take advantage of bootstrap classes

wrap your accordion code with a row, and wrap both of your accordion-group with span6. This way:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="accordion">

<div class="span6">
    <div class="accordion-group">
        ...
    </div>
</div>

<div class="span6">
    <div class="accordion-group">
        ...
    </div>
</div>

</div><!-- closes .accordion-->
</div><!-- closes .row-->
```

Then you can override css to remove undesired margin and padding. Tell me if this is the way you want to show your accordion.

Comment: For a Bootstrap 3 solution, change `span6` to `col-xs-6`. You can change the `xs` to `sm`, `md` or `lg` for responsiveness.

Answer (score 0):

I think I may have an outside solution that will give you the function you're after. It uses jQuery UI rather than Bootstrap though. You may find it easier to work with.

Be sure to check the fiddle there's a lot of css

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/apaul34208/M3mEX/2/)

html

```
<h6 id="click1">Click Me!</h6>

    <div>some content</div>

<h6 id="click2">Click Me Too!</h6>

    <div>some more content</div>
     <h6 id="click3">Click Me Three!</h6>

    <div>wait, there's more content!</div>
</div>
```

js

```
$(function () {
    $(".accordion").show().accordion({
        heightStyle: "content",
        collapsible: true,
        active: false,
        animate: {
            duration: 1000,
            easing: 'easeOutBounce'
        }
    });
});
```